# Swift send data to viewcontroller in different storyboard

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

i'm trying to send an Object to a Viewcontroller in a different storyboard.

Todo so i tried this but its always nil:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let link = list[indexPath.row].link
    self.object.cat = link

  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectContacts")
  self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destVC = segue.destination as! SelectContactsViewController
    destVC.object = object
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SelectContacts") as! SelectContactsViewController
controller.object = link
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

---

`prepareForSegue` is triggered when you use `performSegue`

---

Every vc contains storyboard property which references main storyboard so no need for

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```